# mdfind -onlyin not working in hidden directories recursvily? How to use it properly?

Tags: macos, find, zsh

I am trying to find all files named `doc.py` in one of my virtualevns (called `data_science`), which are all in hidden directory `.virtualenvs` under `/Users/adni` and so I go:

```
mdfind -onlyin data_science  -name doc.py
```

it returns NOTHING.

One hint is thtat is not working recursivly or has some problems with hidden dirs.
If it matters I run it in zsh shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Spotlight doesn't index files or directories whose name starts with a period, or at least they are not shown by `mdfind`.

I couldn't find any documentation about it, but for example `mdfind kMDItemFSName=.bash_history` doesn't find `~/.bash_history` either. If you run `sudo opensnoop` in one shell and `mkdir .a;touch .a/{1..1000};mdimport .a` in another shell, you'll see that files in `.a` are not opened, but if you run `mkdir a;touch a/{1..1000};mdimport a`, files in `a` are opened.